# Magento 2 REST API ship order tracks error

Tags: magento2, api, shipping, rest-api

I can create a shipment for an order via REST API. But when i try to add tracks i get the error: Carrier Code can not be empty.

This is my code:
Array
(
    [items] => Array
        (
        )

```
[notify] => 1
[appendComment] => 1
[comment] => Array
    (
        [comment] => Sent via Parcelforce
        [is_visible_on_front] => 1
    )

[tracks] => Array
    (
        [extension_attributes] => Array
            (
            )

        [track_number] => P2G9999999
        [title] => Parcelforce
        [carrier_code] => custom
    )
```

)

Answer (score 1):

To create a shipment, you need the `order_item_id` of each item to be shipped.

**Endpoint**

```
POST http://<host>/rest/default/V1/order/3/ship
```

where 3 is the order id.

**Headers**

```
Content-Type application/json

Authorization Bearer <administrator token>
```

Body > Data

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "order_item_id": 3,
      "qty": 1
    },
    {
      "order_item_id": 5,
      "qty": 1
    },
    {
      "order_item_id": 11,
      "qty": 1
    }
  ],
  "tracks": [
    {
      "track_number": "1Y-9876543210",
      "title": "United Parcel Service",
      "carrier_code": "ups"
    }
  ]
}
```

**[Reference](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/tutorials/orders/order-create-shipment.html)**

Comment: I dont think you do need the items, if left blank it assumes all items are delivered. Which works fine. But if i try using tracks i then get the error.

Comment: Please check reference url

Comment: I did follow that but it still doesnt work

Comment: The full error is this: [2018-12-12 09:50:26] main.CRITICAL: Could not save shipment {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\CouldNotSaveException(code: 0): Could not save shipment at /public_html/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/ShipmentRepository.php:147, Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\LocalizedException(code: 0): Cannot save track:
Number can not be empty
Carrier Code can not be empty at /public_html/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Shipment/Track.php:90)"} []

Comment: track_number and track_number shouldn't be empty.

Comment: Have you checked ? https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/tutorials/orders/order-create-shipment.html

Comment: Yes i have checked that link. And track_number isnt empty - see above example.